# Implementing a total order ranking in PostgreSQL 8.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, rank, postgresql-8.3

The issue with 8.3 is that `rank()` is introduced in 8.4.

Consider the numbers [10,6,6,2].
I wish to achieve a rank of those numbers where the rank is equal to the row number:

```
rank | score
-----+------
1    | 10
2    | 6
3    | 6
4    | 2
```

A partial solution is to self-join and count items with a higher or equal, score. This produces:

```
1    | 10
3    | 6
3    | 6
4    | 2
```

But that's not what I want.
Is there a way to rank, or even just order by score somehow and then extract that row number?

Comment: Why not upgrade to a current version? Postgres 8.3 is end of life: http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: because, you cant just press a button to upgrade. I am in the process of migrating to 9.1 but i need this to work in 8.3

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want the equivalent of [`rank()` or `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a **row number** equivalent to the [window function `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), you can improvise in version 8.3 (or any version) with a (temporary) [`SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html):

```sql
CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE foo;
    
SELECT nextval('foo') AS rn, *
FROM   (SELECT score FROM tbl ORDER BY score DESC) s;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0e9d2c652ae12201e1ad71d13029d2cd)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/09150d/1)</sub>

The subquery is necessary to order rows *before* calling  `nextval()`.

Note that the sequence (like any temporary object) ...

- is only visible in the same session it was created.
- hides any other table object of the same name.
- is dropped automatically at the end of the session.

To use the sequence in the same session repeatedly run before each query:

```
SELECT setval('foo', 1, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a method using an array that works with PG 8.3. It's probably not very efficient, performance-wise, but will do OK if there aren't a lot of values.

The idea is to sort the values in a temporary array, then extract the bounds of the array, then join that with `generate_series` to extract the values one by one, the index into the array being the row number.

Sample query assuming the table is `scores(value int)`:

```
SELECT i AS row_number,arr[i] AS score
 FROM (SELECT arr,generate_series(1,nb) AS i
   FROM (SELECT arr,array_upper(arr,1) AS nb
     FROM (SELECT array(SELECT value FROM scores ORDER BY value DESC) AS arr
     ) AS s2
   ) AS s1
 ) AS s0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a PK for this table?

Just self join and count items with: a higher or equal score **and higher PK**.

PK comparison will break ties and give you desired result.

And after you upgrade to 9.1 - use `row_number()`.