# Resequence (reorder) in column return false

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Based on mysql:

```sql
SET @ordering_inc = 1;
SET @new_ordering = 0;
UPDATE tasks
SET order = CONCAT("p/", @new_ordering := @new_ordering + @ordering_inc));
```

Result:

```
id | order
21 | p/1
32 | p/2
53 | p/3
```

But in Postgresql not working

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  ordering_inc integer := 1;
  new_ordering integer := 0;
BEGIN
  UPDATE tasks
  SET order = CONCAT('p/', new_ordering = new_ordering + ordering_inc);
END $$;
```

Result:

```
id | order
21 | p/false
32 | p/false
53 | p/false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I tried using `:=` in the query but give a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the expression `@new_ordering := @new_ordering + @ordering_inc` assigns to the variable.

Postgres, on the other hand, evaluates the expression
`new_ordering = new_ordering + ordering_inc` according to standard SQL: it compares `new_ordering` to `new_ordering + ordering_inc` with the equality operator `=`, which yields the `boolean` `false`. When concatenating with `concat()`, that's coerced to text 'false'.

For actual variable assignment see:

- [Store query result in a variable using in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-query-result-in-a-variable-using-in-pl-pgsql/12328820#12328820)

But that's not what you need here. There are various ways to assign sequential numbers.

You could use a (temporary) `SEQUENCE` for the task:

```sql
CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE foo_seq;
UPDATE tasks
SET    "order" = 'p/' || nextval('foo_seq');
```

See:

- [Implementing a total order ranking in PostgreSQL 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522671/implementing-a-total-order-ranking-in-postgresql-8-3/14526639#14526639)

To get a serial number in the table column (with arbitrary order), I would just:

```
ALTER TABLE tasks
  DROP COLUMN "order"
, ADD COLUMN  "order" serial;
```

And if you don't want an arbitrary sort order, you have to `ORDER BY` something. Like by `ORDER BY id`. Using the (standard SQL) [window function `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to generate the sequence. In a (non-standard) `FROM` clause to the [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html):

```
UPDATE tasks t
SET    "order" = t1.rn
FROM  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id)  AS rn FROM tasks) t1
WHERE  t.id = t1.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0670af57753588224a341780f1248a7d)*

See:

- [Update a column of a table with a column of another table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473499/update-a-column-of-a-table-with-a-column-of-another-table-in-postgresql/13473660#13473660)

But, seriously, you wouldn't want to use the [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `order` as identifier. That's begging for trouble.